# Update resource in Universal Windows App XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I need to change a color of application's TextBlocks at runtime in an Universal Windows App.

Universal Windows Apps don't support Dynamic Resources and I've been unsuccessfully exploring a few different ways to change color of TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource MyText}"/>
```

using the style

```
<Style x:Key="MyText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
</Style>
```

My question is: **How can I change the color of the TextBlock at runtime?**

What follows are all attempts to change the color:

---

Initially, I followed this article+video [Dynamically Skinning Your Windows 8 App](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/01/walkthrough-dynamically-skinning-your.html) and I stored `TextColor` in a separate dictionary file that I can swap in and out of `MergedDictionaries`

- `Day.xaml` contains `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColor" Color="#FFDDEEFF" />`
- `Night.xaml` contains `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColor" Color="#FFFFDD99" />`

In code:

```
    ResourceDictionary _nightTheme = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Themes/Night.xaml") };
    ResourceDictionary _baseTheme = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Themes/MyApp.xaml") };

// OnLaunched - I set a default theme to prevent exceptions
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dayTheme);

// Method that changes theme:
        if (NightFall)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(_dayTheme);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_nightTheme);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(_nightTheme);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dayTheme);
        }
```

---

When this didn't work, I thought I need to clear the dictionaries:

```
    ResourceDictionary _baseTheme = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Themes/MyApp.xaml") };
// Method that changes theme:
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_baseTheme);
        if (NightFall)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_nightTheme);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dayTheme);
        }
```

---

I also tried to refresh the frame in the method that changes dictionaries, to no avail

```
        var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        frame.Navigate(frame.Content.GetType());
```

---

In another attempt I tried to create a dictionary at runtime and update it

```
ResourceDictionary _dynamicTheme = new ResourceDictionary();
// OnLaunched
        _dynamicTheme.Add("TextColor", new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Chocolate));
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(_dynamicTheme);
// Method that changes theme
        _dynamicTheme.Remove("TextColor");
        _dynamicTheme.Add("TextColor", new SolidColorBrush(NightFall ? Windows.UI.Colors.Chocolate : Windows.UI.Colors.Cornsilk));
```

---

Finally, I realized that perhaps `StaticResource` makes the color immutable, so I decided to give `ThemeResource` a try. I've modified my themes:

```
<Style x:Key="MyText" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource MyTextColor}" />
</Style>
```

`Day.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTextColor" Color="#FFDDEEFF" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

`Night.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTextColor" Color="#FFFFDD99" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

I swapped the methods in and out of the `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` just like in previous attempts.
Again, the color doesn't change, even if I *fake-refresh* the `Frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue several month ago, i couldn't fix the problem until i came across the following [blog post](http://www.guruumeditations.net/changing-app-theme-on-the-fly-with-requestedtheme) which propose a pretty good generic solution.

Basically what you need to do is :

**First**

add the following helper `Frame` class, which will replace your default `Frame`

```
public class ThemeAwareFrame : Frame
{
    private static readonly ThemeProxyClass _themeProxyClass = new ThemeProxyClass();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppThemeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "AppTheme", typeof(ElementTheme), typeof(ThemeAwareFrame), new PropertyMetadata(default(ElementTheme), (d, e) => _themeProxyClass.Theme = (ElementTheme)e.NewValue));


    public ElementTheme AppTheme
    {
        get { return (ElementTheme)GetValue(AppThemeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppThemeProperty, value); }
    }

    public ThemeAwareFrame(ElementTheme appTheme)
    {
        var themeBinding = new Binding { Source = _themeProxyClass, Path = new PropertyPath("Theme"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
        SetBinding(RequestedThemeProperty, themeBinding);
        AppTheme = appTheme;

    }
    sealed class ThemeProxyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ElementTheme _theme;

        public ElementTheme Theme
        {
            get { return _theme; }
            set
            {
                _theme = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind the `ThemeAwareFrame` class as explained in by the blog post writer is:

> I create a proxy class that will just be used to store the current theme, and, 
>   if the theme is changed, to propagate it. It is a static field, so is
>   shared with all ThemeAwareFrame.
>
> I add an AppTheme dependency property. When it will be changed, it
>   will changed in the proxy class.
>
> In the ThemeAwareFrame constructor, I bind the ThemeRequested property
>   to the proxy class Theme property.

**Second**

Create your **Light** and **Dark** theme resources in the *App.xaml* :

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTextColor" Color="DarkGray" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTextColor" Color="White" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Third**

in the App.Xaml.cs change the rootFrame to a ThemeAwareFrame instead of a simple Frame:

```
rootFrame = new ThemeAwareFrame(ElementTheme.Dark);
```

in the `OnLaunched` method :

```
     protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
     {
    #if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
    #endif
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new ThemeAwareFrame(ElementTheme.Dark);
            // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
            rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }
     //..
```

**Forth**

Use `ThemeResource` instead of `staticResource` when using a Theme related resource :

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource MyTextColor}" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource MyText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Content="Dark Theme" Click="ChangeThemeToDarkClick" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
    <Button Content="Light Theme" Click="ChangeThemeToLightClick" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Finally**

To change your app theme simply change the `AppTheme` property of your rootFrame like this:

```
   private void ChangeThemeToLightClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Window.Current.Content as ThemeAwareFrame).AppTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
    }

    private void ChangeThemeToDarkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (Window.Current.Content as ThemeAwareFrame).AppTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    }
```